# WHERE clause in .cshtml MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, where-clause

I have 3 tables in my database:

1. Categories: ID(PK), CreationDate
2. Languages: ID(PK), Title
3. CategoryDetails: ID(PK), CategoryID(FK), LanguageID(FK), Title, Description

I've also created a ViewModel in MVC 4 with all the tables, but when I'm trying to list the Category Details in the view (.cshtml), the WHERE clause doesn't work as I was expected. 
I'm trying to list the Language not by key, but by Title.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.lstCategoryDetails)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.Title</td>
            <td>@Model.lstLanguages.Title.Where(x => x.ID == @item.LanguageID)</td>
            <td>@item.Description</td>
        </tr>    
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [`Enumerable.Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns another `IEnumerable`, even if this contains just one `found` item. So replace `.Where(` with `.FirstOrDefault(` or `.Single(` etc.
- You also don't need the additional `@` on in the lambda filter.
- Once you've done this, access the `Title` property of the selected `Language`

e.g.

```
@Model.lstLanguages.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == item.LanguageID).Title
```

*Note that you'll get a NRE if the `language` isn't found.*

Comment: It still doesn't work. I got an error: Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'System.Collections.Generic.List<MultilanguageCategories.CORE.Models.Language>' does not contain a definition for 'Title' and no extension method 'Title' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<MultilanguageCategories.CORE.Models.Language>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference

Comment: Updated - Title is a property on Language.

Comment: Oh, the mistake was in the syntax, It works now! Thanks a lot for the help Stuart :)

Answer (score 1):

you should say

```
@Model.lstLanguages.Where(x => x.ID == @item.LanguageID).First().Title
```

you can apply 'where,select etc...' to list, and return type is Ienumerator.

when you apply 'First() or FirstOrDefault()' returns to you element type of your list.

for exm. you have `List<int> intList = (1,2,3,4,5,6).`

and applying:

```
intList.where(p=>p == 4 || p== 5).FirstOrDefault();
```

returns to you '4' as type of integer.